# Unable to install the FlutterFire CLI

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#3

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

I followed the instructions on the above page and executed the above command.
When I did so, I received the following error message.

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.5.

Because pub global activate depends on flutterfire_cli any which requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
```

When I ran flutter upgrade to try it out, I got the following message.

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 77d935af4d (5 weeks ago) • 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
Engine • revision 890a5fca2e
Tools • Dart 2.15.1
```

dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

I then ran the above command again, but still got the same error message.

What should I do?

Comment: upgrade your dart SDK version.

Comment: what is the value of the sdk version in your `pubsec.yaml` (ex. `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have Dart SDK installed with version 2.10.5 separately from the one that came with flutter(Dart v2.15.1). upgrade the Dart SDK with this commands

(MacOS)

```
brew upgrade dart
```

(Windows)

```
choco upgrade dart-sdk
```

(Linux)

```
sudo apt-get install dart
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The reason was that the path to flutter was not set.